# Como cargar imagenes a un slider con ajax jquery mientras se suben otras imagenes a la base de datos al mismo momento?

Tags: jquery, ajax, .net, asp.net-web-api

Alguna idea de como ir cargando imágenes en un slider con Ajax jQuery haciendo varios requests a la Base de datos (voy a usar Web API .Net y los requests a la base van hacer cada 2 minutos) cuando al mismo tiempo desde otro cliente se están subiendo otras imágenes a la misma BD.. Me gustaría saber de algún algoritmo que muestre uma cantidad de veces "justa" las imágenes en el slider teniendo en cuenta el intervalo de 2 minutos dela request y que no comience siempre desde las mismas imágenes así muestra las últimas subidas.

Comment: Este es StackOverflow en Español, las preguntas deben ser formuladas en este idioma

Comment: hola buen día :D investiga sobre SignalR (https://www.asp.net/signalr) es una librería que te permite hacer cosas increíbles en tiempo real. Esto es lo que necesitas para lanzar notificaciones desde la base de datos: http://www.venkatbaggu.com/signalr-database-update-notifications-asp-net-mvc-usiing-sql-dependency/ y en este enlace tambien: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Broadcast-Real-time-SQL-69dd9fcc Cuando lo hagas funcionar, agradecería de tu parte que compartas la respuesta aquí mismo para ayudar al crecimiento del sitio, por cierto, bienvenido!

Comment: y otro enlace más: https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-sql-server

Comment: @fredyfx Muchas gracias Fredy! Apenas tenga novedades lo voy a postear.

Comment: de nada hermano, éxitos con el desarrollo! dale con todo el power 2.0! :D